# Annoying hissing sound from passenger side window

Tags: window

When I exceed 60mph I hear a hissing sound from the passenger side window as if you have havent closed the window propely, I have also installed window vents(see image below) for that sake, and have the windshield replaced (not because of this, but it was [broken](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17674/possible-cause-of-sudden-breakage-of-windsheild) accidentally)

Still this sound doesn't seem to go, should I get the door rubber replaced? where could the air be slipping through?

PS: When I slide my hand along the window I cant feel any air coming in

[image]

Comment: I would check the rubber door seal(s) to ensure they are intact. Could be there is one out of place or has a piece missing.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly sounds like it's the door rubber not sealing properly. On some cars, this is known for getting compressed, and so not pressing fully against the door - sometimes you can resolve this by adjusting the seal or inserting something into the void behind it to push it back out. (I was just watching a video on YouTube for how to do this on my own car...)

What car is it?

Comment: air being compressed - sounds logical, you mean air gets compressed and slips through the space between the door and the body(without entering inside)?

Comment: I think he meant that the rubber or plastic seal gets compressed, and because of that it doesn't seal anymore.

Comment: @Allman - yes, that's exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced noise/air coming into the car from where the door handles are on the inside.  It was exceptionally pronounced in an old Saturn SL2.  You could feel cold air blowing in from outside.  I have also experienced just the noise in a 98 Monte Carlo and other cars I've ridden in.

Are you sure the noise is coming from the top of the window?

It could also be coming from between the door and the "roof".  Check your weatherstripping around your door.  If it is this, it would explain why your window vents haven't helped.

Even if your weatherstripping is good, your car could just have a weird gap around your door that is causing noise.  As a last resort, I would adjust the position of the door by loosening the hinge bolts, moving it a *tiny* bit, and retightening.  This helped with a similar issue on a 98 Dodge Dakota after the door got caught by a very strong wind gust.

Comment: Im not sure if its the top of the window, but its definitely the window side. ok let me try other options before comming to the bolts